# How to return 410 with lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, http-status-code

I have a subdomain with service I am going to kill.

I'd like to use 410 to mark it as such.

Is there a way to do that with lighttpd without resolving to mod_magnet and lua scripts?

Comment: mod_magnet is the right solution for this, and you didn't give a reason why you don't want to use it.

Comment: @Stefan Well, from docs: "While the lua language the mod_magnet uses is very powerful, mod_magnet is not meant to be a general replacement for your regular scripting environment. This is because mod_magnet is executed in the core of Lighty and EVERY long-running operation is blocking ALL connections in the server. You are warned." . But true, I have not tested this so I am probably worried needlessly.

Comment: Ah yes. Well, returning 410 as status code is neither a long running nor a blocking operation, so mod_magnet is fine. long running would be calculating stuff, like compression or prime number generators, and blocking operations refer to local file io or (usually worse) network io (databases, ...).

Answer (score 3):

Set the document root to an otherwise empty directory, and use a [dynamic error handler](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Server_error-handler-404Details) to send a 410 response.

Example:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "gone.example.com" {
  server.document-root = "/var/www/gone"
  server.error-handler-404 = "/gone.php"
}
```

Where `/var/www/gone/gone.php` contains something like the following:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 410 Gone");
header("Status: 410 Gone");
```

Comment: I don't have any dynamic handlers on this server, but otherwise it's fine hack.

Comment: No PHP, perl, Rails, anything else? It doesn't have to be PHP...

Comment: Nope, it delegates backends to other servers through fcgi.

Comment: 1. I recommend using url.rewrite-if-not-file instead of server.error-handler-404, 2. if you don't want mod_magnet it looks like you're searching for something "small" - a fastcgi/php backend is certainly not better.